# How to install Biztalk 2020 Project Templates in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: biztalk, visual-studio-2019, biztalk-2020

I did full install of BizTalk including developer tools (after installing Visual Studio 2019).  I have also done a repair and reboot since then.

I see this .vsdir file on the disk: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server\Developer Tools\BizTalkProjects\BTSProjects.vsdir", but not sure how to make it work with VS2019.

File contains this:

```
Schema Files|{7a51b143-7eea-450d-baef-827253c52e43}|#221|140
BTSFlatFileSchema.vsz|{7a51b143-7eea-450d-baef-827253c52e43}|#134|7|#135|0|229|0|#136
JSONSchemaWizard.vsz|{7a51b143-7eea-450d-baef-827253c52e43}|#144|8|#145|0|229|0|#146
##Documentation about Adding Wizards to the Add Item could be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sc7ft4a.aspx
```

The link in the file refers to a Visual Studio 2014 web page.

Expected result, click "Create New Project" in BizTalk, type BizTalk and be able to pick the template.

I have tried these two commands that might have fixed in older releases, not sure if they are applicable with VS2019:

```
devenv /setup templates 
devenv /InstallVSTemplates
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from [Biztalk 2020 - Project not showing in Visual Studio 2019](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25ed1057-afd8-4d36-bf41-80020a2e2ae7/biztalk-2020-project-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2019?forum=biztalkgeneral)

From the installer:

> ".To use this feature, you must also install the following: BizTalk Project Extension, Enterprise Single Sign-On (SSO) Administration.For more information on this component, click Help. "
>   And the Install BizTalk Server 2020 documentation:

To complete **Developer Tools** component installation, install **BizTalk Server extension** in **Visual Studio.**
To achieve this you need to:

1. Start Visual Studio and load into an empty IDE
2. Click Extensions, Manage Extensions
3. Search the online tab for BizTalk Server:
4. Install the BizTalk Server extension
5. Close all instances of Visual Studio
6. Let VSIX installer complete
7. Start Visual Studio and select BizTalk from the project types

Comment: Yep, I found that blog after I got back from the gym, was about to post the same.  It worked. Thanks.